# Calculus formula doubt

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am having a confusion in some of the formulas of differential and integral calculus.

If $y=\ln x$, then $dy/dx=1/x$ and integral of $\tan x$ is $\log|\sec{x}|$ and also similarly of $\cot x$ and $\sec x$...

So why is it that in differentiation it is on which means base $e$ and in these formulae it is base $10$, please explain.

Comment: The integral of $\tan{x}$ is $- \log{\cos{x}} = - \ln{\cos{x}}$, wherever it's well defined (hence the absolute value). I guess you are confused about $\ln = \log$ which is only a convention. Normally $\log$ is used for both base-$e$ and base-$10$ logarithms, being necessary to be pointed out if this results in confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context of calculus $\ln$ and $\log$ are interchanged commonly. It is purely notation. They both denote the natural logarithm (base $e$). It is very rare to see somebody using the base $10$ logarithm in the context of Calculus.

Comment: ok thanks but otherwise on means base e and log is base 10 right?

Comment: @user166748 Yes. Base 10 logarithms are never really used in mathematics as such but rather in the sciences. So it depends purely on the context. For calculus, algebra etc. $log$ will mean base $e$. If it is a science context it is a good bet that it is base $10$ especially if $\ln$ was used to denote the natural logarithm elsewhere. The most important thing is to stay consistent with notation eg. Use only one of them to keep things clear.